# Convert an array of variable and give it a numpy array structure

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array of data in a variable `flux1` and when I type

```
print(flux1)
```

in python console I got a data array as

```
[2.93066965e-06 3.09537578e-06 2.80267259e-06 ... 3.14786615e-06 2.42937392e-06 2.47956683e-06]
```

there is 40 000 values in there.

I want to structure this `flux1` as in `np.random.random((200, 200))`
generated array.

Comment: `flux1.reshape((200, 200))`?...

Comment: Thanks, man, I did not reload the tab to see your comment, In the meantime, I found the solution and post the answer. Now I see you also posted it.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it, All I had to do was:

```
np.reshape(flux1, (200, 200))
```